# How good can the graphics get on a game made only with Python?

Tags: graphics, python

Aside from the game being fun, which is the most important, is it possible to make a "good looking" game with it?  The graphics I mean.  Like Angry Birds.  Could that be made in python, looking like it does (you know, good).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=7oZC6DpIUhQ

No, it's not mine.  I don't know anything about it.  But, I like the way it looks.  It, however, is written in Java (I saw it on the java-gaming forum).

Also, I don't mean using Panda3d or another C++ engine with Python as the game logic.  All in Python and based on some Python library (I don't have to totally reinvent the wheel.)

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty subjective question. Beauty is in the eye of the coder.

Comment: @Byte56 While I agree somewhat, you cannot tell me what you don't know what a good looking game is.  C'mon guys.

Comment: You're familiar with the site rules right? Like the "[Primarily opinion based](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" close reason?

Comment: @Byte56 absolutely but I think they're being translated in a wooden fashion here.  This is not strictly opinion based.

Comment: If you don't want strictly opinions you need to quantify "good looking".

Comment: @Byte56 This is not a forums so I won't go on, but, I think we all know what I'm asking.

Comment: Alrighty. jhocking's answer, while not directly answering the question, answers why the question doesn't need answering.

Comment: You will end up with using OpenGL for python anyways. Unless you want to make use of software blitting which is rather outdated compared to quad meshes or using spritebatching. And then there is PyGame : http://www.pygame.org/news.html (D3D & OpenGL based trough SDL )

Comment: Angry birds looks good because of the quality of its art style, not so much technical graphical capability.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your comment "based on some Python library" could very well be a "C++ engine with Python as the game logic".

Second, the quality of your graphics is almost never related to the programming language you choose. In part because of, well, the first point.

Comment: I don't understand then.  How can a C++ engine be a Python only game?

Comment: @johnny A lot of engines make use of script bindings so that they can apply changes without recompiling data.